# Axapta: Convert utcDateTime to date

Tags: datetime, x++, axapta

What is the best way to convert a utcDateTime value to a date type so I can use the global datetime functions on it?

```
int timeDiff;
date _now = systemdateget();
;

select firstOnly myUTCDateTime from _myTable
timeDiff = Global::yearDiff(_now, _myTable.myUTCDateTime);
info(strfmt('%1', timeDiff);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [DateTimeUtil Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc619601.aspx) has methods for dealing with utcdatetime variables. In your case you would use `DateTimeUtil::date`.

```
timeDiff = Global::yearDiff(_now, DateTimeUtil::date(_myTable.myUTCDateTime));
```

Answer (score 5):

Logic for utcdatetime :

```
utcdateTime  testDonedateTime1;
utcdateTime  testDonedateTime;
transdate    tmpDate ;
timeofday    tmpTime;

testDonedateTime1 = inventJournalTable.PostedDateTime;
testDonedateTime  = DateTimeUtil::applyTimeZoneOffset(testDonedateTime1, DateTimeUtil::getUserPreferredTimeZone())
tmpDate = DateTimeUtil::date(testDonedateTime);
tmpTime = DateTimeUtil::time(testDonedateTime);
```

Important : utcDateTime control properties TimeZonePreference set No conversion

Answer (score 2):

```
utcDateTime         _dateTime = 2012-12-31T13:59:58;
date                _date;
;

_date = DateTimeUtil::date(_dateTime);
info(strFmt('%1',_date));
```

Comment: Where is the explanation? Please share with us.