# Using date part only of CreatedDateTime field in while select statement

Tags: datetime, while-loop, axapta, x++, ax

How can one group by a table based on only the date part of the CreatedDateTime field in X++ in dynamics AX? I can use the following statement in the sql server and get what I want but I don't know the way to do same in X++.

```
select  COUNT(RECID) from WMSORDERTRANS
GROUP BY CAST( FLOOR( CAST( CREATEDDATETIME AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME )
```

In X++ I tried,  DateTimeUtil::date(wmsOrderTrans.CreatedDateTime) but I cannot use it in while select statement.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to group on a calculated field in AX.

You can create a view then make a computed field, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13304175/4509).

By the way, this is [the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052621/4509) to convert to local date.